# How to Bypass Web Server Errors with ASP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an MVC web application and trying to tell the Web server to "get out of the way" and let my application handle serving the error message.

I have proofed this out with an ASP.NET framework application but not with ASP.NET Core and trying to see if this possible. For more context I have linked the guide I followed when I was testing this within [ASP.NET](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/01/Bypassing-IIS-Error-Messages-in-ASPNET).

I am just trying to see if it is possible to show an error like:

[image]

*(Please note - the image above is from an IIS server | the desired outcome is still the same.)*

... instead of seeing an error like:

[image]

If anyone has any idea of how I can do this - please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For showing developing errors, you could try `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`.

In general, you should only use this in Development mode, you should not expose this error message to end user.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
           app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
           // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
           app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: @jdave What do you mean by `why UseHsts would work for this case`? I suggested to use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`.